# Changing page count with PrintDocumentAdapter and PrintManager

Tags: android, pdf, printing

I'm extending PrintDocumentAdapter to send roster information to a printer via Cloud Print. Everything is working well, until the settings are changed so that the number of pages in the document is decreased.

For example, a table will fit on two A4 pages, but will require three A5 pages. Cloud Print starts with A4 selected by default and a preview is generated. If the page size is changed to A5, a new preview is generated with three pages as expected. If the page size is then changed back to A4, Cloud Print gives the message "Sorry, that didn't work. Try again." and must be exited.

This is what seems to be happening:

- onLayout() is called with A4 document attributes. LayoutResultCallback.onLayoutFinished() is passed a PrintDocumentInfo pageCount set to 2.
- onWrite() is called with a single PageRange of 0-1, as expected.
- I change the paper size to A5.
- onLayout() is called with A5 document attributes. LayoutResultCallback.onLayoutFinished() is passed a PrintDocumentInfo pageCount set to 3.
- onWrite() is called with a single PageRange of 0-1, **which is the old range**
- onWrite() is called a second time with the correct PageRange of 0-2.

This only causes an error when the old PageRange is greater than the number of pages returned, but why would onWrite() get called with an invalid PageRange?

I've noticed many apps on my device simply scale the output so that the page count doesn't change between different settings. Are they doing this due to this problem?

```
public class PrintAdapter extends PrintDocumentAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = "PrintAdapter";

    private PrintedPdfBuilder mPrintedPdfBuilder;
    private int mPages;

    public PrintAdapter(PrintedPdfBuilder printedPdfBuilder) {
        mPrintedPdfBuilder = printedPdfBuilder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes,
                         CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback,
                         Bundle extras) {

        Log.v(TAG, "onLayout");
        // Respond to cancellation request
        if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
            callback.onLayoutCancelled();
            return;
        }

        int pages = mPrintedPdfBuilder.getPageCount(newAttributes);
        Log.v(TAG, "page count = " + pages);
        if (pages > 0) {
            // Return print information to print framework
            PrintDocumentInfo info = new PrintDocumentInfo
                    .Builder("print_output.pdf")
                    .setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT)
                    .setPageCount(pages)
                    .build();
            // Content layout reflow is complete
            callback.onLayoutFinished(info, mPages != pages);
            mPages = pages;
        } else {
            // Otherwise report an error to the print framework
            callback.onLayoutFailed("Page count calculation failed.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onWrite(PageRange[] ranges, ParcelFileDescriptor destination,
                        CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback) {

        Log.v(TAG, "onWrite() ranges: " + Arrays.toString(ranges));
        // Write PDF document to file
        try {
            PrintedPdfDocument pdf = mPrintedPdfBuilder.generateDocument(ranges);

            // check for cancellation
            if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                callback.onWriteCancelled();
                mPrintedPdfBuilder.close();
                return;
            }
            pdf.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(destination.getFileDescriptor()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            callback.onWriteFailed(e.toString());
            return;
        } finally {
            mPrintedPdfBuilder.close();
        }

        PageRange[] writtenPages = mPrintedPdfBuilder.getWrittenPages();
        Log.v(TAG, "writtenPages: " + Arrays.toString(writtenPages));
        // Signal the print framework the document is complete
        callback.onWriteFinished(writtenPages);
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
08-28 11:46:44.187 9714-9714/com.meremammal.www.staffrosterwizard V/PrintAdapter: onLayout
08-28 11:46:44.276 9714-9714/com.meremammal.www.staffrosterwizard V/PrintAdapter: page count = 2
08-28 11:46:44.298 9714-9714/com.meremammal.www.staffrosterwizard V/PrintAdapter: onWrite() ranges: [PageRange[0 - 1]]
08-28 11:46:44.512 9714-9714/com.meremammal.www.staffrosterwizard V/PrintAdapter: writtenPages: [PageRange[0 - 1]]
08-28 11:46:50.418 9714-9714/com.meremammal.www.staffrosterwizard V/PrintAdapter: onLayout
08-28 11:46:50.499 9714-9714/com.meremammal.www.staffrosterwizard V/PrintAdapter: page count = 3
08-28 11:46:50.509 9714-9714/com.meremammal.www.staffrosterwizard V/PrintAdapter: onWrite() ranges: [PageRange[0 - 1]]
08-28 11:46:50.678 9714-9714/com.meremammal.www.staffrosterwizard V/PrintAdapter: writtenPages: [PageRange[0 - 1]]
08-28 11:46:50.918 9714-9714/com.meremammal.www.staffrosterwizard V/PrintAdapter: onWrite() ranges: [PageRange[0 - 2]]
08-28 11:46:51.160 9714-9714/com.meremammal.www.staffrosterwizard V/PrintAdapter: writtenPages: [PageRange[0 - 2]]
08-28 11:47:34.983 9714-9714/com.meremammal.www.staffrosterwizard V/PrintAdapter: onLayout
08-28 11:47:35.049 9714-9714/com.meremammal.www.staffrosterwizard V/PrintAdapter: page count = 2
08-28 11:47:35.056 9714-9714/com.meremammal.www.staffrosterwizard V/PrintAdapter: onWrite() ranges: [PageRange[0 - 2]]
08-28 11:47:35.248 9714-9714/com.meremammal.www.staffrosterwizard V/PrintAdapter: writtenPages: [PageRange[0 - 1]]
```

onLayout is called each time the settings change, but for some reason onWrite is then called with the previous PageRange[]

Comment: Still an issue as of 2018. Ran into the problem today and reproduced exact same results. Did you ever find a work around?

Comment: @AaronBar Check out my answer. Works in Pie till Marshmallow.

Comment: still page range is not updated correctly, any solution to this ? year 2020 :)

Answer (score 1):

I trapped the NullPointerException error and displayed a message to the user to Retry. This will catch the error and display your message to the user along with a Retry button which then succeeds because the pageRanges have been updated.

```
    @Override
    public void onWrite(final PageRange[] pageRanges,
                        final ParcelFileDescriptor destination,
                        final CancellationSignal cancellationSignal,
                        final WriteResultCallback callback) {
        // Iterate over each page of the document,
        // check if it's in the output range.
        int requestedPageCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < mTotalPages; i++) {
            // Check to see if this page is in the output range.
            if (containsPage(pageRanges, i)) {
                //########## Add in this Try Catch Block   #############
                try {
                //######################################################
                    PdfDocument.PageInfo newPage = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(mPageWidth,
                            mPageHeight, i).create();
                    PdfDocument.Page page =
                            mPDFDocument.startPage(newPage);
                    if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                        callback.onWriteCancelled();
                        mPDFDocument.close();
                        mPDFDocument = null;
                        return;
                    }
                    if (mPrintJobType == PrintType.LIST) {
                        drawPageList(page, i + 1, (mPageWidth < mPageHeight));
                    } else {
                        drawPageDetail(page, i);
                    }
                    mPDFDocument.finishPage(page);
                //######## Catch the error here and display a message
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    //Catch a known error thrown thrown by pageRanges not being updated in a timely manner.
                    callback.onWriteFailed("We found a bug in the Android operating system. " +
                            "Please click Retry to continue.");
                    return;
                }
                //##################################################
            }
        }

        // Write PDF document to file
        try {
            mPDFDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(
                    destination.getFileDescriptor()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            callback.onWriteFailed(e.toString());
            return;
        } finally {
            mPDFDocument.close();
            mPDFDocument = null;
        }
        callback.onWriteFinished(pageRanges);
    }
```

Comment: This actually works so well that it could be in commercial products. But remove the text "We found a bug in the Android operating system. Click Retry to continue." to a space causes the user to press it again and the reason is not their concern. You can't have a text that says the OS sucks to users, when you make apps for it? You can write such a comment in Stack overflow, but not to users.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the **Party of Printer Zone!!**

***The below is not with respect to Cloud Printing, But still putting out the answer for anyone looking for solution wrt changing printing attributes and system throwing error.***

After changing the attributes, from following options, system was throwing error.

[image]

For local printer request using `PrinterDocumentAdapter` , the below worked. A change in the `onLayout` method.

```
public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, ....
```

Change the default implementation of return value to false. Rest system will take care.

```
@Override
    public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras) {
        Log.d(TAG,"MyPrintDocumentAdapter onLayout ");
        if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
            callback.onLayoutCancelled();
            return;
        }
        if (mTotalPages > 0) {
            PrintDocumentInfo.Builder builder = new PrintDocumentInfo
                    .Builder(mFileName)
                    .setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT)
                    .setPageCount(mTotalPages);

            PrintDocumentInfo info = builder.build();
            callback.onLayoutFinished(info, false);// Second param should be false
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "onLayout Error in page count");
            callback.onLayoutFailed("Page count is zero.");
        }
    }
```

I am sending InputStream from my activity to Custom Document adapter. Below is the full source for the same.

First read the content from any location (Memory / Assets etc) . Next using InputStream showing Document for printing.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CancellationSignal;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.print.PageRange;
import android.print.PrintAttributes;
import android.print.PrintDocumentAdapter;
import android.print.PrintDocumentInfo;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MyPrintDocumentAdapter extends PrintDocumentAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private static InputStream mTargetDocStream;
    private String mFileName;
    private String TAG = MyPrintDocumentAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private int mTotalPages;
    public MyPrintDocumentAdapter(Context context, InputStream docFileStream, String fileName, int totalPages) {
        Log.d(TAG,"MyPrintDocumentAdapter Constructor");
        this.context = context;
        mTargetDocStream = docFileStream;
        mFileName = fileName;
        mTotalPages = totalPages;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras) {
        Log.d(TAG,"MyPrintDocumentAdapter onLayout ");
        if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
            callback.onLayoutCancelled();
            return;
        }
        if (mTotalPages > 0) {
            PrintDocumentInfo.Builder builder = new PrintDocumentInfo
                    .Builder(mFileName)
                    .setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT)
                    .setPageCount(mTotalPages);

            PrintDocumentInfo info = builder.build();
            callback.onLayoutFinished(info, false);// Second param should be false
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "onLayout Error in page count");
            callback.onLayoutFailed("Page count is zero.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback) {
        Log.d(TAG,"MyPrintDocumentAdapter onWrite ");
        try {
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(destination.getFileDescriptor());
                byte[] buf = new byte[16384];
                int size;
                while ((size = mTargetDocStream.read(buf)) >= 0
                        && !cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, size);
                }
                if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                    callback.onWriteCancelled();
                } else {
                    callback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES});
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                callback.onWriteFailed(e.getMessage());
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception in onWrite = " + e.toString());
            } finally {
                try {
                    mTargetDocStream.close();
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "IOException = " + e.toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException onWrite = " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I made it false. it prevented additional call of the OnWrite method, but as the Page range attribute is not updated, the error persists